# How to initialize a class containing objects in angular model.ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i have a model.ts in my angular

```
export class BooksModel{
   constructor(
       public bookName: string,
       public bookAuthor: string,
       public bookCategory: string,
       public bookDescription: string,
       public bookFile : {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },
    public bookImage : {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },
   ){}
}
```

i want to initialize this model class but i dont know how to initialize objects inside these class.

```
 bookItem= new BooksModel("","","","","","");
```

Comment: You should pass all required data, params bookFile  and bookImage are objects

Comment: how to do that? my data from db contains bookImage:{data: Buffer, contentType: String} which i am not able to save in frontend.because bookItem= new BooksModel() gives error

Comment: Perhaps in some part of your application there are already some examples, try to search "BooksModel" in your project

Comment: this is my only bookmodel, but this contains object buffer so when i try to initialize  bookItem= new BooksModel("","","","","","");  this line gives me error. because "" is for string and my model contains object

Comment: I dont know from where the Buffer type comes from, but for instance to initialize a bookItem you can do something like this

bookItem= new BooksModel("My test book","Someone","SomeCategory","SomeDescription",{ data: null, contentType: "image/jpeg"}, { data: null, contentType: "image/jpeg"});